# Mysql Trigger not working while updating history table

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I want to update **history** table using below trigger

```
CREATE    
    TRIGGER `trig_Update_transaction` AFTER UPDATE ON `transaction` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN     
      UPDATE transaction_history SET OLD.deliverystatus=NEW.deliverystatus
      WHERE OLD.alertID=NEW.alertID;      
    END$$
```

What is problem here?

Comment: are you unable to create this trigger or you have created but it is not updating?

Comment: i am unable to update table , trigger was created

Comment: i think that you have mentioned 'history' in bold but you want to update transaction_history table. Hope this is not the catch. Right?

Comment: no no that’s not issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem in these lines:

```
UPDATE transaction_history SET OLD.deliverystatus = NEW.deliverystatus
WHERE OLD.alertID=NEW.alertID;
```

**From MySQL documentation**:
 In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have the SELECT privilege), but not modify it.

For details, refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

I would also love to read from community on this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `OLD` alias in the Trigger definition. OLD and NEW aliases refers to subject(one being affected by original query) table.

`UPDATE transaction_history SET deliverystatus=NEW.deliverystatus WHERE alertID=NEW.alertID;`